# Error while starting a powershell job using scriptblock and argumentlist

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I need to execute powershell file, test.ps1, from test1.ps1. I am using start-job feature of powershell. In my test1.ps1, I have

```
$pathToFile = (Join-Path -Path $PSSCriptRoot -ChildPath "test.ps1")
$ar = $a, $b # all these variables have values assigned 
Start-Job -Name job2 -ScriptBlock{& $pathToFile -fName $args[0] -lName $args[1]} -ArgumentList $ar
```

In my test.ps1, I have fName and lName as parameters like:

```
param([string]fName, [string]lName]
```

I keep getting the following error:

> The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that
>   was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a
>   CommandInfo object.

The problem is here `Start-Job -Name job2 -ScriptBlock{& $pathToFile -fName $args[0] -lName $args[1]} -ArgumentList $ar`

But I don't seem to find the solution to resolve this issue.And Yes, I verified that $pathToFile contains exact path to test.ps1 => C:\foo\test.ps1
Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

After a few hours of research, I finally made it work.

The solution is to use `$using:pathToFile`.

So, instead of using

```
Start-Job -Name job2 -ScriptBlock{& $pathToFile -fName $args[0] -lName $args[1]} -ArgumentList $ar
```

the solution is to use this:

```
Start-Job -Name job2 -ScriptBlock{& $using:pathToFile -fName $args[0] -lName $args[1]} -ArgumentList $ar
```

I hope this will help other folks.

Answer (score 0):

it should also work like this:

```
$pathToFile = (Join-Path -Path $PSSCriptRoot -ChildPath "test.ps1")
$ar = $a, $b, $pathToFile  # all these variables have values assigned 
Start-Job -Name job2 -ScriptBlock{& $args[2] -fName $args[0] -lName $args[1]} -ArgumentList $ar
```

so you must pass the absolute path into the arguments variable

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the invoke-expression cmdlet?
This is what I usually use.

Invoke-Expression [-Command]  [ ]

Comment: This has little to do with the OP's question, which boils down to a local variable not being defined when run in the context of a job.